# How to access global variable in subroutine

Tags: perl

Suppose, my global variable and local variables has same name, how can i access the global variable value in subroutine?

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

$name = "Krishna";

sub printName{
 my $name = "Sankalp";

 print ("Local name : ", $name, "\n");
 # How to print global variable here
}

&printName;
print("Global name : ", $name, "\n");
```

Comment: Don't forget to `use strict; use warnings;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your *global* variable is in fact a package variable, you can access it through the package namespace. The default package is `main`.

```
print "Local name : $main::name\n";
```

Since you're staying in the same namespace, you can omit the `main`, so `$::name` works, too. Both solutions **do not work** if your outside variable was also defined using `my`.

You can define a package variable with [`our`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html) or via `use names qw($name)`.

---

That said, you should never do that. Always use lexical variables, and put them in the smallest scope possible. `use strict` and `use warnings` will help you, and there is [a Perl::Critic rules that complains](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::Variables::ProhibitReusedNames) if you define a variable with the same name as an existing one in a smaller scope.

Comment: Does not work.  Got error  `Variable "$name" is not imported at xxx.pl  line yy`

Comment: Forget to mention: not working if  "use strict" is used.

Comment: @RobinHsu how did you declare that variable? The error indicates you didn't. Also, what Perl version is this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare a package variable instead of lexical variable using [`our`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html). Inside a subroutine you need to fully qualify it to address it. If you need to share variables across packages you should use our.

[`my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) declares the variable in lexical scope. So, the variable dies once it is out of scope. These variables are also private and can't be acessed by other packages.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

our $name = "Krishna";

sub printName {
    my $name = "Sankalp";
    print ( "Local \$name: ", $name,"\n" );
    print ( "Global \$name: ", $main::name, "\n" ); # or $::name inside the same package
}

printName;
print( "Global name : ", $name, "\n" );
```

Comment: You were actually faster :)

Comment: Yes, verily I was :). But, you were more precise.